# JSS Headless mode issue

Tags: jss, sitecore-api

I am trying to run my local jss app in headless mode. 
while trying to hit the jss service, I am not getting the expected o\p.
I can the security info object has `401` as statuscode.

[image]

If I try hitting the jss item from Sitecore itself, I can see the data. No `auth` issues. But when  trying the same from headless mode, I see this security issue.

Any clue as to what is missing in here?

Comment: How do you hit the the JSS item from Sitecore itself? is the sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/{url}&sc_apikey={key}&sc_site={site}&sc_lang=en  working?